# Ajaxify - url with internet explorer 8+9 /#./profile

Tags: jquery, ajax, history

Using Ajaxify works great with modern browsers but with IE8 + 9 I have some strange URL behaviour getting `http://domain.com/#./profile` instead of  `http://domain.com/profile`

Is this a known "feature" or do I miss something?

http://browserstate.github.io/history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js

http://rawgithub.com/browserstate/ajaxify/master/ajaxify-html5.js

Answer (score 1):

It's a known feature. IE < 10 doesn't support the history API, so your library is falling back to the hash hack.

See the [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) documentation, specifically the section starting "Working with History.js directly" (although classing browsers as "HTML 4" or "HTML 5" depending on support for the history API seems overly general to me).

Comment: Thanks much for your help but is it common to have a #. url? I have seen hash bang #! or just # at other sites... perhaps this is configurable? Or are there reasons for exactly that url scheme?

Comment: The hashbang is for Google's [horrible hack to make Ajax urls crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started). The history API renders it redundant.